# Can a PWA hosted in a cloud service be installed locally and access a local REST API server?

Tags: networking, progressive-web-apps

That's basically my question.

Is there any way to have a PWA accessible in a public cloud service and when the user install it, locally, it can access a local REST API server to retrieve information?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be a CORS error. You may be able to get around it by getting script from localhost to call the API on localhost.

Comment: CORS for sure will be something to deal with, but first I need to know if the PWA installed locally can communicate directly with the REST API server without going outside, cloud service, to send the request.

Comment: Other that CORS, I'm not aware of any limitation on calling services, regardless of the location.  Should be a pretty quick thing to prototype to be sure, before developing a larger program around the design.

Comment: Because the PWA is hosted in a cloud service, the PWA should send the request through that cloud server, right? And it will not work, the cloud server can not 'see' the local REST API server. This is what I don't know, if there is a way the installed version of the PWA, in a machine that is connected to the same LAN as the REST API server, can send the request directly, without going outside.

Comment: I think you can get around the CORS requirement, if you call your local service, using JavaScript code downloaded from your local server.  Make a simple .JS file for example https://localnetwork/localservice.js.  Have your PWA reference the localservice.js file.  In your localservice.js, you can make fetch calls to the REST API on https://localnetwork/restapi